# Next step with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am building a rails app that will when finished allow users to register, create a property and then assign tenants and rents to that property.

So far I have the property section completed, meaning that I can log in as a new user and create a property. My next step is to allow users to add tenants to their properties and I was wondering what is the best way to assign re-occurring rents to each tenant?

Do I add a 'starts_at' & 'ends_at' field to each new tenant created? I think that this is the road I will have to take as I want each rent payment to re-occur every month. So if a user creates a tenant with a lease starting 10/26/2012 and ending 10/26/2013 there will be a re-occurring monthly rent for 12 months.

I was thinking of creating a tenant scaffold and then creating a rents scaffold and connecting the two with:

TENANT - has_one :rent

RENT - has_many :tenants

Does this sound like I'm on the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your relationships are backward:

```
class Tenant < AR::Base
    has_many :rents
end

class Rent < AR::Base
    belongs_to :tenant
end
```

Since rent contains the dates, and there will be 12 rents in a year per tenant, the relationship is that `Tenant` will have_many `Rents` That wording is a little awkward, so you might want to rename `Rent` to `Payment`

For dealing with the recurring rent/payment, I would look at a gem like ice_cube. Here's a list of gems that do recurring events, including ice_cube: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/recurring_events
Dealing with repeating dates can get very ugly very quickly!